Is there a trick to placing stairs?
I have a terrible time placing stairs in my structures in a settlement. I feel like I must be doing something wrong. When I try to line it up with the gap in the second floor it never seems to snap/turn green in the right spot. Sometimes I can't even find a spot where it will even turn green. Secondly, the landing included with the stairs at the top always comes up short of the floor so I need to jump over the last hump. I even tried putting a floor piece below it with no luck.
Am I missing something?
BTW: This is on the PC platform via Steam.

Things that might be wrong:
A: There are 2 types of height in Fallout 4 constructions, namely the base one (Wood & Metal are without any DLC and concrete requires the Wasteland DLC) and the Barn(Far Harbor DLC)/Warehouse(Contraptions DLC) one. the later ones are higher. So if you have walls from those and stairs from the regular ones it won't fit. So best is to use stairs from the same sub-menu.
B: The Floor/roof issue. Some square pieces are floors, some are roofs and some function as both. The base ones (Wood/Metal/Concrete) often have one of each, while the Barn and Warehouse only have the later one so that works for all Stairs both going up and down.
A stair won't be able to snap downwards if the targeted tile is a "floor" only tile, even if it's a second level floor.
My advice would be to only use the Barn/Warehouse structures seeing they have more variations and are generally speaking more detailed and flexible.
